# modifying strings as arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I cannot understand why my `word[1]` returns an `a` instead of an `i`, could you help me understanding it?

```
var word = 'tangle';
document.write(word[1]); //returns 'a'
word[1] = 'i';
document.write(word[1]); //returns 'a'
```

(truth is, I wanted to make this, is my method wrong?)

```
//convert the first letter of each word of the string in upper case
var string = 'the quick brown fox';
stringSpl = string.split(' ');
for (var j=0; j<stringSpl.length; j++){
  stringSpl[j][0] = stringSpl[j][0].toUpperCase(); //this line is the faulty one
}
document.write(stringSpl.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable; rather than modifying them, you have to create a modified copy.

Note that `word[1]` is just syntactic sugar for `word.charAt(1)`; just as you wouldn't expect `word.charAt(1) = ...` to modify the character returned by `word.charAt(1)` (because it's not returned by reference), you can't expect `word[1] = ...` to do so, either.

For your example, you can write something like this:

```
var string = 'the quick brown fox';
var titleCasedString =
  string.replace(/(^| )( )/g, function ($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1 + $2.toUpperCase();
  });
document.write(titleCasedString); // writes 'The Quick Brown Fox'
```

(using [the `replace` method of string objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)).

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Javascript.

> In JavaScript, strings are immutable objects, which means that the characters within them may not be changed and that any operations on strings actually create new strings. Strings are assigned by reference, not by value. In general, when an object is assigned by reference, a change made to the object through one reference will be visible through all other references to the object. Because strings cannot be changed, however, you can have multiple references to a string object and not worry that the string value will change without your knowing it.

Source: David Flanagan, in his book "[JavaScript, The Definitive Guide, 4th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0613911881)" (ISBN: 978-0613911887).

Comment: Cite your sources. Who wrote this text?

Comment: Edited answer with source.

Answer (score 0):

`String`s are not `Array`s, but you can use an indexer syntax (similar to that of `Array`s) to get characters from them.

You cannot, however, **set** elements using the same syntax.

Use `String.prototype.split` to create an `Array` from a `String`.